# How to redirect all non-existing subdomains/pages to root domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have no experience in coding at all...I would like to redirect all subdomains and their non-existing pages to the root domain, is it possible to do it via htaccess?

eg. sub1.domain.com , sub2.domain.com , sub1.domain.com/not_exist.html , sub2.domain.com/not_exist.pdf , etc. all of these redirect to root domain: domain.com

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do via `.htaccess` - you're going to use `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}`. Better to handle it via the Apache config, though - look up "default VirtualHost".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! But if you don't mind, please kindly share some details on how to do it :)  Like it said, i don't have any knowledge on coding at all....much appreciated!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=default+virtualhost+apache